# What tool can PRESERVES the dates - timestamp (access, modify, change) while moving files to another file system?

Tags: timestamp

I have 3 of the shelve NAS. I believe they run Linux. I don’t know which file system they use. I access these NAS from Windows through SMB.

I need to service them. Replace all hard drives. Copy everything of, service the NAS, copy everything back. I want that the timestamps stay unchanged.

With what tool can I do that? Can it be done from Windows? Does it need to be Linux? rsync for Windows?

Comment: Have you tried robocopy?

Comment: I tried robocopy. It worked as expected. Thank you.